# How can add decimal in calculator with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, decimal

I need help with my decimal button in my calculator. Its working now somehow but i need to perfect it more and kinda don't know how. So if you know a way how to make it better please help. So if you know how to fix it please do. Thank you.

1. How can add decimal in printOutput
2. The issue is when i press number and after i press decimal it works for example 2.34 but the problem is you can press decimal after every number making it for example 2.3.4 and thats not what i want.

this is a javascript code >>>>>>>

```
function getHistory() {
  return document.getElementById("history-value").innerHTML;
}
function printHistory(num) {
  document.getElementById("history-value").innerHTML = num;
}
function getOutput() {
  return document.getElementById("output-value").innerHTML;
}
function printOutput(num) {
  if (num == "") {
    document.getElementById("output-value").innerHTML = num;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("output-value").innerHTML = getFormatNumber(num);
  }
}

function getFormatNumber(num) {
  if (num == "-") {
    return "";
  }
  if (num.length > 10) {
    num = num.substr(0, 10);
    alert("it tooo much!");
  }
  var n = Number(num);
  if (n === "Infinity") {
    value = "0";
    alert("Error");
  } else {
    var value = n.toLocaleString("en");
  }
  return value;
}

function reverseNumberFormat(num) {
  return Number(num.replace(/,/g, ""));
}

let operator = document.getElementsByClassName("operator");
for (let i = 0; i < operator.length; i++) {
  operator[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (this.id == "clear") {
      printOutput("");
      printHistory("");
    } else if (this.id == "backspace") {
      let output = reverseNumberFormat(getOutput()).toString();
      if (output) {
        output = output.substr(0, output.length - 1);
        printOutput(output);
      }
    } else {
      let output = getOutput();
      let history = getHistory();
      if (output == "" && history != "") {
        if (isNaN(history[history.length - 1])) {
          history = history.substr(0, history.length - 1);
        }
      }
      if (output != "" || history != "") {
        output = output == "" ? output : reverseNumberFormat(output);
        history = history + output;
        if (this.id == "=") {
          let result = eval(history);
          printOutput(result);
          printHistory("");
        } else {
          history = history + this.id;
          printHistory(history);
          printOutput("");
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

let number = document.getElementsByClassName("number");
for (let i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
  number[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    let output = reverseNumberFormat(getOutput());
    if (output != NaN) {
      output += this.id;
      printOutput(output);
    }
  });
}
```

```
      <div id="calculator">
        <div id="result">
          <div id="history">
            <p id="history-value"></p>
          </div>
          <div id="output">
            <p id="output-value"></p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="keyboard">
          <button class="operator" id="clear">C</button>
          <button class="operator" id="backspace">CE</button>
          <button class="operator" id="%">%</button>
          <button class="operator" id="/">&#247;</button>

          <button class="number" id="7">7</button>
          <button class="number" id="8">8</button>
          <button class="number" id="9">9</button>
          <button class="operator" id="*">&times;</button>

          <button class="number" id="4">4</button>
          <button class="number" id="5">5</button>
          <button class="number" id="6">6</button>
          <button class="operator" id="-">-</button>

          <button class="number" id="1">1</button>
          <button class="number" id="2">2</button>
          <button class="number" id="3">3</button>
          <button class="operator" id="+">+</button>

          <button class="number zero" id="0">0</button>
          <button class="operator" id=".">.</button>
          <button class="operator" id="=">=</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Some change are necessary**

First (1) : Change dot  **`.`**  operator className to `number` as illustrated below

```
<button class="number" id=".">.</button>
```

Second (2): In `getFormatNumber` replace it with this update  .

```
function getFormatNumber(num) {
  if (num == "-") {
    return "";
  }
  if (num.length > 10) {
    num = num.substr(0, 10);
    alert("it tooo much!");
  }

  // to check whether a dot is placed just a the end of num like 6.
  let lastIndexOfDot  = num.toString().lastIndexOf(".") ; 
  let isDotted  =lastIndexOfDot  == false ? false: lastIndexOfDot == num.length-1 ? true : false ; 

  var n =  Number(num); 

  if (n === "Infinity") {
    value = "0";
    alert("Error");
  } else {
    var value = n.toLocaleString("en");
  }
   // if dotted is true then value has a dot at the end like : 5. so we return value  with its dot 
   if (isDotted ) return value +"." ; 

   return value;  // no dot at the end 
}
```

-Third (3 ) In `handler` of all element belonging to `class number` replace it with this new `event handler`

```
let number = document.getElementsByClassName("number");
for (let i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
  number[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    let output = reverseNumberFormat(getOutput());

    if (output != NaN ) {
      output += this.id;  
      // CHECK HERE IF output is already a valid decimal number 
      let matchCount = output.match(/\./g) ;
    
      if( matchCount && matchCount.length > 1 ) return  ; // => already decimal number 
      printOutput(output);
   }

 });
}
```

Four in  (4)  in `reverseNumberFormat` function replace it with this

```
function reverseNumberFormat(num) {
  return num.replace(/,/g, "");  // => Nb: conversion not necessary
}
```

NB: It is helpfull and It works on my side but don not hesitate to inform me  for any bug or problem in the future .

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution for the "problem is you can press decimal after every number making it for example 2.3.4 and thats not what i want".If you simply want to avoid multiple decimals it can be used.

```
function printOutput(num) {
  if (num == "") {
    document.getElementById("output-value").innerHTML = num;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("output-value").innerHTML = getFormatNumber(num,document.getElementById("output-value").innerHTML);//since i want to check with the current value
  }
}
function getFormatNumber(num,prev_value) {
 const split_prev_value = prev_value.split(""); //this will give your string into ['s','t','r'...]
 if(split_prev_value.some((ele)=>ele==='.')){ //checking that if "." already exists in the prev_value and return empty string if already exists
  return "";
 }
 else{
  return ".";
 }
}
```